# should I use server cluster when my application does not work with session

Tags: java, architecture, java-ee, cluster, load-balancing

I read about payara(glassfish) server cluster and find out that clustering with payara only replicate session in multiple servers.

but I use jwt for my project so I don't use session at all.

I decided not to cluster servers and just use multiple servers without connecting to each other and have Load Balancer in-front of them, Am I losing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you losing anything ?
Depends on whether you are dependant on the j2ee specs. For example JCA,  If not then stay away.

Stateless services are way more flexible in terms of Scalability.

And more over its easy to refactor to microservices.